# Problem with using wp-load.php outside of WordPress

Tags: customization, outside-wordpress

I'm trying to use wp-load.php in a page outside of wordpress so I can access all the functions in wordpress.  Typically I just include the file like this

```
require( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/blog/wp-load.php' );
```

But it doesn't seem to be working.   Any tips on what can be going on?

Thanks,
Paul

Comment: This turned out to be a server config issue not a wordpress issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Including wp-load.php will not setup the WordPress query.

See [Integrating WordPress with Your Website](http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website) for the right way.